# How to connect javascript in Amazon S3 bucket to Amazon time server?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ntp

I have a javascript project that is currently deployed in an Amazon S3 bucket. On the page, there is a clock that I would like to sync up to a time server to provide more accuracy. I have code currently, to try and connect, but am not sure what to do to sync up to the time server correctly:

```
  try {
        //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "169.254.169.12", false);
        xmlhttp.send();

        var dateStr = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Date');
        var serverTimeMillisGMT = Date.parse(new Date(Date.parse(dateStr)).toUTCString());
        var localMillisUTC = Date.parse(new Date().toUTCString());
        return serverTimeMillisGMT -  localMillisUTC;

    }
    catch (err1) {
        //IE
        try {
            var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "169.254.169.12", false);
            xmlhttp.send();

            var dateStr = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Date');
            var serverTimeMillisGMT = Date.parse(new Date(Date.parse(dateStr)).toUTCString());
            var localMillisUTC = Date.parse(new Date().toUTCString());
            document.getElementById("serverTime").innerHTML = "This clock is synced to a time server.";
            return serverTimeMillisGMT -  localMillisUTC;
        }
        catch (err2) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "169.254.169.12", false);
                xmlhttp.send();

                var dateStr = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('Date');
                var serverTimeMillisGMT = Date.parse(new Date(Date.parse(dateStr)).toUTCString());
                var localMillisUTC = Date.parse(new Date().toUTCString());
                document.getElementById("serverTime").innerHTML = "This clock is synced to a time server.";
                return serverTimeMillisGMT -  localMillisUTC;
            }
            catch (err3) {
                //use CPU time.
                console.log("using machine time...");
                document.getElementById("machineTime").innerHTML = "This clock is synced to machine time.";
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

I currently have the IP address of the time server (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/windows-set-time.html#windows-configuring-ntp), but that does not work.

Thoughts on how to sync with the Amazon Time Server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF the JavaScript is running on Amazon S3 then this will be being served as a front-end application (unlink NodeJS which is server-side).

Without being able to call a backend you will be limited to the system time of the users local machine if you're looking for a purely frontend solution to your problem.

If you wanted to sync using Amazons servers you would need to make use of a backend app which can get this time from server its running on rather than the users machine.

This would be possible most simply by setting up an [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) and [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) combination, but you would need to be aware there will still be the latency of round trip of the users machine connecting to the API and then receiving the response.